# What's so secret about my hat, anyway?

Tags: discussion

and why aren't I at least told if it's *my* secret hat?

[image]

and why isn't it a hat?

....hmmm....

[image]

Comment: Because you are a whistleblower :P

Comment: @Braiam - what happened to your face!?!?

Comment: Perhaps your definition of "hat" is too narrow, hmm?

Comment: If you wore it on your head then it would be a hat

Comment: @Matt - sometimes its the simple things that stump me. i think you just solved all of my problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The secrecy is not in the hat, of course, but in how you gain it.

It's explained in the user-maintained [list of secret hats on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270837/270345):

> [Miller guessed it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats/270837#comment877745_270837) - posting an answer with 0 comments on a question with 0 comments, and the answer reach score of 7.

Comment: thats a big thread. now, why isnt it a hat? i thought it might have something to do with the 007 in my rep count. right after asking this question i switched back to the main page and took that last picture. nobody seems to think that at the link, though.

Comment: Because it goes *on* your avatar, of course... like a hat goes on your head.

Comment: yup. that nicely rounds it out. thanks, @muru.

Comment: i think that odinson answer is wrong there.

Comment: @mikeserv I just got it, and I did cast the initial close vote on [a post closed by a dupehammer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249421/70524). (As did you.)

Comment: you did? i just got it too. oh. xdg-open, then, i guess? so... i read it wrong then? i thought the answer for the odinson thing was that it was only given to the dupehammer people.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the second part of your question: uh, well, you see, it's a *secret* hat, and since 007 is a *secret* agent, er, the actual headgear part of the hat, y'see, it's um, just *invisible*, 'cause it's a high-tech spy gadget thing...

Okay, fine. You got us. The design of this hat went through several iterations, and we finally ended up in a spot where we had a trigger and a name we really liked, but without an actual hat, because James Bond doesn't have a single truly iconic hat, at least that I'm aware of. Rather than try to keep fiddling with the rest of the design, I just gave up on making all hats literal headcoverings (which, if it's any consolation, is a bit of a personal disappointment).

At any rate, congratulations on your non-hat!

Comment: consider me consoled.

Comment: by the way - about the trigger - is it supposed to imply some kind of *espionage* - or illicit affiliation between asker/answerer? cause *that's* funny.

Comment: You're reading too much into it. It's designed to reward good askers and good answerers. Good askers, because they don't need anyone commenting to say "hey you left out some critical piece of info, please edit/fix." Good answerers, because they similarly don't need anyone commenting to say "okay answer but part three is wrong." The asker is rewarded with a very good answer and the answerer is rewarded with a hat (and a bunch of upvotes).

Comment: yeah, but... it was more funny the other way. also - aren't you forbidden from revealing that or somethng? im telling. anyway, your hat is cool.

Comment: woah. youve got the monkey face hat.

Comment: Yeah, apparently, just enough people [didn't like what I did with Greeter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312447/).

Comment: dont sweat it. i opted out of the hat thing last year but im glad i didnt this year - this is a *sweet* tux. and thats a *sweet* monkey face hat. there really should be an *i hate hats* hat, though.

Comment: How would people know they had it? It'd be, like... Schrödinger's hat.

Comment: and that would make it *fun*.